# Can be any ActiveX component used as COM object?

Tags: c#, c++, com, activex

I don't clearly understand difference between `COM` and `ActiveX` terms. So I confused: can I use *any* ActiveX component as COM object?

I have an ActiveX component, it can be used from browser as well. But  I want use this component as COM object (I have library that can use COM objects, but in library description nothing wrote about ActiveX)?

Comment: ActiveX is a technology based on COM, so each ActiveX Component IS A COM-Object (or at least inherits from an COM interface). You want to use ActiveX components as COM objects - so what have you tried so far?! Your question does not actually give enought information to answer it.